# Groovy : Attempting to parse a date

Tags: java, groovy

I am attempting to parse a date string using groovy but running into issues. Here is what the string looks like and logic which isn't working.

```
def dateString = "2017-01-01T12:00:00Z"
def date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", dateString)
```

Ive also tried

```
def date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", dateString)
```

which doesn't parse either. Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

Running script:

```
def dateString = "2017-01-01T12:00:00Z"
def date = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", dateString)
println date
```

Produces following output:

```
Sun Jan 01 13:00:00 CET 2017
```

#### Comparing `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX`

You need to consider supporting timezone offset in dates you are parsing. Check following script run with current timezone set to Europe/Warsaw:

```
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", dateString)
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX", dateString)
```

It will produce two different result:

```
Sun Jan 01 12:00:00 CET 2017
Sun Jan 01 13:00:00 CET 2017
```

First one treats `Z` as a literal and parses given date and time using current timezone. It means that when you run this script using different current timezone set, you will get again `12:00:00` in this timezone.

Second one takes timezone information into account and treats `Z` not as a literal, but as a `GMT/UTC` timezone notation. So in case of my timezone correct time is `13:00:00` and not `12:00:00`.

There is also another issue with the first format. If you start receiving dates like `2017-01-01T12:00:00+0400` you will get following exception when the first pattern is used:

```
Caught: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-01-01T12:00:00+0400"
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-01-01T12:00:00+0400"
    at avg.run(avg.groovy:35)
```

Second one parses given `dateString` with explicit timezone offset with no issue and prints:

```
Sun Jan 01 09:00:00 CET 2017
```

which is correct date and time for my current timezone.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Also escaping Z like this `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` works as well. Just figured it out.

Comment: @mcroteau `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'` does not returns same result. I'm in CET time zone and your format returns `Sun Jan 01 12:00:00 CET 2017` for given date which is not valid I think. `dateString` contains date and time in UTC timezone, so it should be represented supporting current timezone I think.

Comment: @mcroteau I've updated my answer to show the difference between both patterns and what are possible issues you may run into when using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the break down of information. I will use X instead of escaped Z.